# Unable to grab dates into a column

Tags: r, date, subset, quantmod

While using `quantmod` and scraping GOOGLE stock prices I want the dates and it is showing the dates but unable to subset the dates.

```
library(quantmod)
start <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2017-11-01")
getSymbols("GOOGL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
```

Snapshot: [image: R programming]

What should I do?

Comment: See `?xts` for and `?window.zoo` for two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

The `xts` class (a superset of the zoo class which stores the time data as rownames rather than in numeric columns) has a method for "[" that can be used. It parses dates as characters and uses "/" to separate the ends of intervals:

```
G.subset <- GOOGL["2017-01-01/2017-11-01"]
```

Read more at:

```
?`[.xts`
?xts
```

The time values are accessible with the `index` function.

Comment: I can grab the dates but want to store it in a column, I'm not getting that part. index function was what I was looking for.

Comment: The coredata of an 'xts' object is a matrix so it cannot hold R Dates which are made date-like by virtue of their class. R matrix columns cannot have class attributes. Learn to deal with R packages as they are, not as you fantasize them to be.

Comment: I'm a noob, learning R since 1 month. It'll take some time to get adjusted to packages.